# Python: setting the zero value color in a contourf plot, where log scale colorbar is required

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a contour plot from some data files. The trouble I am having is that I want the z-values below the minimum on the color bar to be the same color as the minimum value.
This is easy when using a linear scale using e.g. the `extend="both"` option for the `contourf`, or using `cmap.set_under()` for the colormap. Unfortunately neither of those options work when using a logscale. Can anyone suggest a workaround? I just want to get rid of the white areas in the plot below:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
from matplotlib import colors, ticker, cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
N = 100 #number of points for plotting/interpolation

y, x, z = np.genfromtxt(r'40Ca_208Pb_39K_Ex_115deg.dat', unpack=True)

xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')

hfont = {'fontname':'Palatino'}

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="white")

zi = np.ma.masked_less(zi, 1e-7) 

plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi,levels=[1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1],cmap=plt.cm.jet,norm = LogNorm())

plt.xlabel("$E_{x}$")
plt.ylabel("$E/V_{B}$") 
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you think that `set_under` is not working properly you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue. Here you just mask the array to be plotted, so the masked parts are simply not plotted at all. You cannot set any color to something which isn't plotted. On the other hand you may simply change the background color of the axes to the color of your liking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `extend` keyword not working with a log scale is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7942) with `matplotlib`.

A crude workaround would be to coerce all the values into the drawn range (notice the comments on the `min_drawn_value` and `max_drawn_value`, the values must be inside that range):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

N = 100  # number of points for plotting/interpolation
min_exp = -8
max_exp = -2

min_drawn_value = 1.000001 * 10.**min_exp  # above 10.**min_exp
max_drawn_value = 0.999999 * 10.**max_exp  # below 10.**max_exp

xi = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
yi = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
zi = np.random.rand(N, N) *\
     10. ** np.random.randint(min_exp - 1, max_exp + 2, (N, N))
zi = np.sort(zi.flatten()).reshape(N,N)

# Coerce values outside of colorbar range to lie within
zi_masked = np.where(zi < 10.**min_exp, min_drawn_value, zi)
zi_masked = np.where(zi_masked > 10.**max_exp, max_drawn_value, zi_masked)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

c1 = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=10.**np.arange(min_exp, max_exp+1),
             cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=LogNorm())

c2 = ax2.contourf(xi, yi, zi_masked, levels=10.**np.arange(min_exp, max_exp+1),
             cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=LogNorm())

ax.set_title("direct plot of array")
ax2.set_title("coerce outlier values")
fig.colorbar(c1, ax=ax)
fig.colorbar(c2, ax=ax2)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In how far is this different from the code in the question? It also uses a masked array. So values outside are not plotted. Or did I misunderstand the code?

Comment: In the `above 10.**min_exp` and below `10.**max_exp`, because if the values are equal to the limits they get plotted as white. Should have pointed that out, will edit.

Comment: I see. I took the liberty to edit your answer; I think it is now much clearer. If you disagree, just roll back to the previous version.